# This required file could not be found: geometry.sty

Tags: miktex, texlive, installing, geometry, texworks

I am trying to set up LaTeX on my PC using TeXworks. I'm trying to run the ejc-sample.tex template from the Electronic Journal of Combinatorics:

https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/about/submissions

But, when I click the Typeset button, I get this window, which reads "This required file could not be found: geometry.sty" followed by "the file is a part of this package: geometry" There is then a field labelled "The package will be retrieved from this source:" with the field set for "" next to a button reading "Change...". This is followed by another field labelled "This package will be installed for:" and set for "".

There are two buttons at the bottom, "Install" and "Cancel". Regardless of which button I press, the typesetting stalls without making any further progress. Pressing the "Change..." button opens a new window with some option to select various things, but I have no idea what, if anything, I need to select, in order to allow the template to finish typesetting.

[image]

Comment: `TeXWorks` is a _front end_ editor and PDF previewer, it tries to guess which backend tex installation you have and doesn't always do so correctly. If you are on Windows: did you install TeXLive or MikTeX? You will need to install the `geometry` package using the correct backend, or you will need to configure TeXWorks to use your backend correctly.

Comment: If this is the first time you tried using and setting up TeX, and my previous comment caused some head scratching, it may help if you describe the process (steps) by which you got TeXWorks onto your PC so that other can figure out what is missing.

Comment: This is the first time in years that I've tried to set up and use TeX (and the first time ever on a PC). I Googled "install latex on pc" which took me here:

https://www.latex-project.org/get/#google_vignette

Under Windows, there were two options: MikTek and Tek Live. I tried MikTek first, but it gave an error saying "The code execution cannot proceed because MikTeX230100-png.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix the problem." However, it wouldn't let me re-install the program because the directory wasn't empty, and it wouldn't let me delete the directory because...

Comment: ...it said it was in use, even after closing every process related to MikTex. After that failed, I went with plan B and installed TeX Live, which did work, and let me run basic "Hello world" scripts just fine. But, when I used the template from the Electronic Journal of Combinatorics, I started getting the message about the geometry package.

Comment: Just press install when you see the image you posted

Comment: Further update. It looks like it is MikTeX that is driving my TeXworks. There were two MikTeX logos that appeared when I type it into the Windows search, and the second one did open and let me install packages, but only individually. While going through all the packages it eventually got to the point where I had to reboot. After rebooting I now get that "The code execution cannot proceed because MikTex230100-web2c.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem." message from TeXworks itself and can't even get to the point of it having to install any packages.

Comment: Search for the miktex console and try to install the package there. Check there also if there are updates.

Comment: I tried, once again, deleting and re-installing MikTeX. And I checked for updates and didn't find any.  However, the "Typeset" button still doesn't work (nor does the menu option. Now, the "Console output" window in TeXworks just reads "Process crashed" without any further information.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured out how to get it to work. Here's what I did:

1. Reboot the computer (you need to do this to be able to remove MikTeX).
2. Delete every trace of MikTeX from the computer and cast it into the fires of Mount Doom.
3. Salt the Earth so MikTeX will never grow there again.
4. Uninstall and re-install TeX Live.
5. Run TeXworks with TeX Live.